# Enable or disable a <i> in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable all the `<i class="icon-add user">` inside `class=container` only, when a `.user` is clicked, but don't seem to be succeeding. There are other `<i>`, but they don't need to be touched. I'm stuck only with the disable, enable part. Can you help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user").click(function(){
        console.log('Was clicked');
        $('.container.user').attr('disabled', 'disabled');// Disable all links

        $('.container.user').attr('disabled', '');// Enabled later by the script on success
    });
});

<div class="container">
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: disabling doesn't work in non-ie browsers, does it?  I thought standards only allow that attribute on inputs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `$('.container.user')` means elements with both classes `container` and `user`. To select descendant you need space between `.container` and `.user` You are using `i` tag you might need to use `a` for anchor. Also you are enabling and disabling in the same event so your first setting will be overwritten.

*Change*

```
$('.container.user')
```

*To*

```
$('.container .user')
```

The attr() is setting the disable property but not disabling the click. Using off to remove event to detach the click event, you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/e27ct/).

Comment: You are talking about link do you want a tag instead of i ?

Comment: I'm trying to disable the <i> so a user wont be able to click it.

Comment: To can remove the click event from it

Comment: The method to enable them again is `on`? How do I enable them again?

Answer (score 1):

Your `selector` is wrong use `.container .user` in place of `'.container.user'`

and use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user").click(function(){
        console.log('Was clicked');
        $('.container .user').prop('disabled', true);// Disable all links    
        $('.container .user').prop('disabled', false);// Enabled later by the script on success
    });
});
```